# Is the derivative of a monotone function non-negative a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I know that a monotone increasing function $f$ is differentiable a.e. I want to immediately say that $f' \ge 0$ where it exists but I do not actually have a proof. I only think it is true from intuition of continuous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a countable number of jump discontinuities.

If $h > 0$, then $f(x+h) \geq f(x+)$ and $f(x-) \geq f(x-h)$ and the derivative must be non-negative  where  it exists.

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\geq 0 \implies \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\geq 0$$

$$\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}\geq 0 \implies \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}\geq 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let the function $f$ be monotone non-decreasing. Then wherever the derivative of $f$ exists, it must be non-negative. This follows from the definition of the derivative. If $\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}\lt 0$, there must be an $h\gt 0$ such that $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}\lt 0$, and hence $f(a+h)\lt f(a)$.